# IBM Cloud Object Storage: Get bucket size using CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

I'm trying to find a way to automate the task of getting COS bucket sizes on IBM Cloud.

I have dozens of buckets over different accounts but still couldn't find a way to get this information using [IBM Cloud COS CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli), just other information, like bucket names, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The [COS S3 API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-compatibility#list-buckets) does not return size information for buckets. Thus, the CLI, which is based on the API, won't return size information either.

But here's an indirect way to find the size of a bucket by looping through the sizes of the individual objects in the bucket

```
ibmcloud cos objects --bucket <BUCKET_NAME> --output JSON | jq 'reduce (.Contents[] | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value) | .Size'
```

The output is in **bytes**

You may have to loop through the bucket names may be in a shell script. For all the buckets in an account + resource group, run the below command

```
ibmcloud cos buckets --output JSON
```

**Note:** Before running the above commands, remember to add the COS service CRN to the config with the below command

```
ibmcloud cos config crn --crn <SERVICE_CRN>
```

Comment: Regarding that last Note, is there a way to get the CRN using the CLI? All I can find is how to list the items in the service catalog (`ibmcloud catalog service cloud-object-storage`).

Comment: found it: `ibmcloud resource service-instance <instance-name>`

Answer (score 1):

The answer that loops through the individual objects is indeed the only (and likely best) way to use the IBM Cloud CLI to find that information, but there are a few other ways worth mentioning for completion.

If you need to do this elegantly on the command line, the [Minio Client](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-minio) provides a Linux-esque syntax:

```
mc du cos/$BUCKET
```

This returns the size of the bucket in MiB.

Additionally, the [COS Resource Configuration API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-configuration#getbucketconfig) will directly return a `bytes_used` value, with no iterating over objects behind the scenes.  While there's no official CLI implementation yet (although it's in the pipeline) it's relatively easy to use cURL or httpie to query the bucket.

```
curl "https://config.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v1/b/$BUCKET" \
     -H 'Authorization: bearer $TOKEN'
```